# ReactJS - Display a grid on the whole web page

Tags: reactjs, grid, react-component

I am trying to display a grid on the whole web page composed of small cells with equal heights/widths like the example shown below and I looking for a way to do that since this is my first react project:

[image]

this is Main.jsx

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Node from './Node/Node';

import './Main.css';

export default class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            nodes: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        const nodes = [];
        for(let row = 0; row < 15; row++){
            const currentRow = [];
                for(let col = 0; col < 50; col++){
                currentRow.push([]);
            }
            nodes.push(currentRow);
        }
        this.setState({nodes})
    }

    render(){
        const {nodes} = this.state;
        return(
            <div className="grid">
                {nodes.map((row, rowIndex)=>{
                    return <div>{row.map((node, nodeIndex)=><Node></Node>)}</div>
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

this is Node.jsx:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import './Node.css';

export default class Node extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }

    render(){
        return <div className="node"></div>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `html table` instead of the `div`, inside of it, you will need to map an array of `<tr>`, composed of an array of `<td>`.

Here is a non-compiled example of the logic :

```
<table>
    {Array(65).fill(0).map(() =>
        (<tr>
            {Array(65).fill(0).map(() =>
                <td></td>
            )}
        </tr>)
    )}
</table>
```

This is just to illustrate the logic. The numbers 65 are what you will need to compute based on the width of your cells and the total width and heights of the user screen.